# чтение из базы mysql

Tags: php

Как прочитать из базы данных последнюю строчку. Браузер выдает ошибку:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   string given in /home/... on line 20

Код:

```
$query="SELECT id,z,i,count FROM log ORDER BY 'id' DESC limit 1";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1];
    echo $row[2];
    echo $row[3];
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема в том, что mysql_fetch_array() принимает первый параметр resource создаваемый mysql_query, а вы передаете ему строку.

**Пожалуйста, прекратите использовать расширение mysql**...Оно устарело и не поддерживается, оно небезопасно из-за отсутствия плейсхолдеров.

Используйте Mysqli или PDO, что в последнем случае позволяет реализовать ООП подход.

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
$query="SELECT id,z,i,count FROM log ORDER BY id DESC limit 1";
$stm = $pdo->query($sql);
$result = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo $result->count;
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем Вы передаёте строку ($query) вместо mysql_query($query); ?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id,z,i,count FROM log ORDER BY 'id' DESC limit 1");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row[0];
    echo $row[1];
    echo $row[2];
    echo $row[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам же пишет, что вы передаете строку вместо результата запроса.  Вот что нужно

```
$sql = "SELECT id,z,i,count FROM log ORDER BY 'id' DESC limit 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);// Вы забыли выполнить запрос
```